# Installing the Blackberry JDE Plugin in Eclipse doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, jde

I followed this guide:

http://www.thinkingblackberry.com/archives/21/comment-page-1#comment-104

Installed the JDE 4.7 and 4.5 packs, and when I try to start a new project, there is no option for "Blackberry Project" at all.

When I click "Help > Software Updates > Installed Software" I see the "Blackberry Component Pack 4.7.0" installed, and I can view its properties. But there's no other evidence of it actually being installed or working.

Does anyone know how to get this going?

Answer (score 4):

- Did you follow [this process](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp) ([detailed here](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp) and in "[BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp)") and use an update site? (new updates available as of Aug 3, 2010)

  http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java
- Did you tried this with a fresh installation of eclipse3.4 (and the [latest JDK, with the right **eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/144349#144349)?)
- Could you try it actually with eclipse3.5 ([latest JDK and **right eclipse.ini**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590))?
  The p2 mechanism has been debugged/enhanced in 3.5, and  does manage well update sites.

As shown in this picture, you should see a "Blackberry" menu (between the "Run" menu and the "Window" menu), if the plugin has been installed properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it had installed properly without any errors, it would show up under Window-Preferences->Blackberry-Installed Components. In the drop down box you should see all the component packages that were installed successfully

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after a fair bit of mucking around was able to get this working.  (They sure don't make it easy.)

Here's what I did:

Delete any existing eclipse installs, as well as workspaces and the .eclipse folder in your  folder.  Download and unzip Eclipse 3.4 (Ganymede - last year's version.  It won't work with the current version.)  I'm using 3.4 SP2, and that seems to work.  Place the unzipped directory whereever you like.  (Mine's in c:\Program Files.)

Next, copy the Blackberry JDE plugin Zip file in an Eclipse extensions folder.  Wherever you decide to put this, Eclipse will remember.  I created an "Extensions" folder in my Eclipse directory and dropped it in there.

Open a command prompt, navigate to your Eclipse directory and run Eclipse.exe with the -clean flag.  ("eclipse -clean")

Click on the "Help" menu and select "Software Updates..."  Click on the "Available Software" tab, then the "Add Site..." button.  In the dialog that comes up, click on the "Archive..." button and browse to your extensions folder and select the Blackberry plug-in .zip file and click "Open."

Click "Install..." and let it install.  When it's done, it will prompt you to restart Eclipse -- Do so.

For me, at this point it was working, and my BlackBerry menu was visible.  Your mileage may vary, but I hope it works for you too.

Andrew

Here are some links I found useful in putting the above together:
http://docs.google.com/View?docid=ah8534h97tx2_30fx947kc
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/eclipseplug_updatesite.jsp
http://prosciutto.boutiquestartups.com/index.php?op=ViewArticle&articleId=55&blogId=1

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact kind of problem with Eclipse 3.5. Worked on it on and off for over a week. Never got a good solution. I noticed that when I did the install it was saying "blocking" and it would take several hours to do the install. I tried it from work and from home. It still took hours. Most of the time it failed. One time it finally worked (or seemed to), but there were missing menu options. I suspect the error message is wrong. I'm not sure where the problem is - with OS or SP or java version - no idea.  But there's a much easier solution.

Short answer, I've gotten marginal success using an alternate method of install. Try this: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/devtools.jsp

Click on "Download the BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.1 (full installer)"

It seems to install correctly and MUCH quicker (on the order of a few minutes as opposed to hours), no error messages, no warning messages - and the expected menu items are there.